# Compare recurring dates in php

Tags: php, date

If I have fixed date field in MySql format: 2015-02-01, how can I do comparison, so that every month a message will popup to a user;

For example on every

```
2015-03-01, 
2015-04-01,
2015-05-01,
```

...

This needs to run infinite.

if current date > than 30,60,90 days 
print message.

Or maybe I should use cookie instead and just check the timestamp?

Comment: i'd store something in their db row like `last_message_shown`. if its over 30 days, show them a message and update it. plus you can pull it when you grab their records so you're not spending an extra query.

Comment: Why haven't you tried the solution you provide with cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [datetime.diff](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.diff.php). Transform the SQL request into datetime field, like this example.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('now'); // Get the current day
$datetime2 = new DateTime($SQLResult1); // The day you want to check

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2); // DO the difference

if($interval->format('%a') >= 30)
  echo '30 days passed';
```

Adapt it to your code